# How to display a message and then redirect in Java

Tags: java, servlets

I am working on a Java based registration page. The index page has a form that is filled out and then posted to local database. As of now when submitted it displays a message that states data was entered or not. I cannot figure out how to have that message displayed temporarily and then redirect it to a different page. Below is my Java Servlet.

```
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Register
 */
@WebServlet("/Register")
public class Register extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Register() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        String id = request.getParameter("Id");
        String first = request.getParameter("First");
        String last = request.getParameter("Last");
        String email = request.getParameter("Email");
        String phone = request.getParameter("Phone");
        
        User user = new User(id, first, last, email, phone);
        
        RegisterDao rDao = new RegisterDao();
        String result = rDao.insert(user);
        DateBean dBean = new DateBean(); /** import bean **/
        Date dateTime = dBean.getDateTime();
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println(result + " " + dateTime);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }

}
```

Comment: That is not possible to do on the backend. You can make the front end code redirect with meta tags or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I did a work around. I added a html link to the display message to click to bring the user back to the home page.